# Android 11 - Scoped storage - move DocumentFile to java.io.File

Tags: android, android-11, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

I'm delving into SAF and Scoped Storage. I'll avoid any comment on the whole experience, Christmas is around the corner.

When trying to move a `DocumentFile` to a `java.io.File` folder with the new provided [DocumentContract.moveDocument](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsContract#moveDocument(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.net.Uri,%20android.net.Uri)) APIs:

```
DocumentFile documentFile=...
File outputFolder=...
DocumentsContract.moveDocument(getContentResolver(), documentFile.getUri(), documentFile.getParent().getUri(), DocumentFile.fromFile(outputFolder).getUri())
```

I always get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI`:

```
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.myapp/backup
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:172)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:142)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.call(ContentProviderNative.java:732)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.call(ContentResolver.java:2405)
    at android.provider.DocumentsContract.moveDocument(DocumentsContract.java:1514)
    at com.myapp.tasks.MoveFolderTask.move(MoveFolderTask.java:77)
```

Reading on other SO threads, I understand this is because of the transformation from `java.io.File` to `DocumentFile` by means of

```
DocumentFile.fromFile(outputFolder).getUri()`
```

But I have no idea on how to work around this. `outputFolder` permission is granted by default being an app-specific folder returned by [Context.getExternalMediaDirs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalMediaDirs()). Is the problem in the `Uri` generation?

Any suggestion is welcome.
thanks
nicola

Comment: AFAIK, `moveDocument()` is to move documents within SAF. You appear to be trying to "move" a document to a file. For that, you would need to copy the content to the file, then delete the document.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare - I'm trying to move a whole folder, that's why I'm using the supposedly-provided move API. Any suggestion apart from looping through all files and folders and copy over? It's such an overkill for something that was a one liner, without even discussing about how this is a obvious problem when storage space is scarce

Comment: "Any suggestion apart from looping through all files and folders and copy over?" -- no. "It's such an overkill for something that was a one liner" -- you seem to be thinking that the documents that you are copying from are local. There is little guarantee of that. There are a variety of document providers, from Google Drive to SMB/CIFS providers, where the documents are across a network. A key principle behind the SAF is to abstract away those differences. What you think of as "move" really is "export" or "backup", with an associated removal of the original data.

Comment: I understand this, but we're talking about local and if there's no such way anymore to do it efficiently it feels like moving backward, am I wrong? The end customer experience is terrible and slow for sure, plus much more error prone. Sorry for the polemic tone, not on you of course!

Comment: "but we're talking about local" -- you are talking about local. "if there's no such way anymore to do it efficiently it feels like moving backward" -- if you mean that there should be more options for interoperating between SAF `Uri` values and the local filesystem, where document providers can perhaps provide more efficient solutions, I agree. Alas, Google did not do that.

Comment: You may want to consider why you are starting with a `Uri`, if your end destination is the filesystem. Note that [the deprecated functions on `Environment`, like `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`, are undeprecated](https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/11/06/about-environment-undeprecations.html). And, you have read access to public items on external storage. So, perhaps you can skip the move operations.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I'm a long-time fan (and customer) of your work, and even getting a reply from you is a huge ego boost  Problem is, even after getting scoped permission to access an Uri at Android/media/someotherapp, you cannot access it through java.io.file, I experimented on that and would like to be proven wrong, but empirically speaking you always get permission denied exceptions. Therefore no 'sane' process at the moment to copy/move such folders.

Comment: "even after getting scoped permission to access an Uri at Android/media/someotherapp, you cannot access it through java.io.file" -- I think that location maps to one of `getExternalMediaDirs()` on `Context`, and I am not surprised that you are encountering problems there.

Comment: Just to wrap it up and have some form of closure: it's currently not possible to use `moveDocument` to move to a `java.io.File`, since it's not possible to build a corresponding/correct `Uri` - the only way is to loop, retrieve each `InputStream`, copy then delete the original source. Please correct me if I'm wrong or still missing some pieces of the puzzle!

Comment: "Please correct me if I'm wrong or still missing some pieces of the puzzle!" -- for your specific scenario, I believe you are correct.